# Extra the word 'numberstyle' in listing

Tags: listings, strings

What's wrong with this ? I define listing style like below.

```
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}


\lstdefinestyle{mysqlStyle}{
    language=SQL,
    tabsize=4,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize, 
    frame=tab,
    columns=fixed,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbers=left,
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{red}
    numberstyle=\color[rgb]{0.205, 0.142, 0.73},
    stepnumber=1,
    aboveskip={1\baselineskip},
    morekeywords={[1]bigint,nvarchar}
}
```

and when i use it

```
\begin{latin}
    \begin{lstlisting}[style=mysqlStyle]
    INSERT INTO [Table] (id,name) 
    VALUES (0,'Karo');
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{latin}
```

it returns me this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed `comma (,)` in line `stringstyle=\color{red}`.

```
\lstdefinestyle{mysqlStyle}{
    language=SQL,
    tabsize=4,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize, 
    frame=tab,
    columns=fixed,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbers=left,
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    numberstyle=\color[rgb]{0.205, 0.142, 0.73},
    stepnumber=1,
    aboveskip={1\baselineskip},
    morekeywords={[1]bigint,nvarchar}
}
```